To make correctly backup of my PC Windows 11 in my SSD
I bought a SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD to backup my PC. According to the recommendation, I used Acronis True Image for Western Digital. I asked to update the Backup hourly because of the frequency of new files for work.
I looked at the SSD and don't understand what appened. There is a lot of files named DESKTOP(number).tibx created every few time (every of them is great, 63G). Moreover, I tried to open a file, a PDF, and this is not possible.
I assume something is going wrong.
Additionally, I see that in every Backup there is files C:, SYSTEM, Ext4(63-5), WinRE_DRV.
I am also an user of Dropbox and the SSD is itself backed up by Dropbox.
I want the SSD to be a replica of the content of the PC and one replica only, with frequent update.
I'm interested to read an explanation why this is not what appened in my attempt to do so.

DESKTOP(number).tibx is your backup.  The number is based on the type of backup you did. Can you provide us with specifics?

It sounds like you’re not backing up your entire HDD without seeing what you have selected for the backup. I cannot answer your question even as a user of Acronis.

I select whole computer @Ramhound

I followed the Acronis and choose to backup the whole PC instead of select folders

When you mount the image. How many partitions are offered to be mounted

@Ramhound There are options BACKUP, TOOLS, SETTING, ABOUT, UPGRADE. I choose Backup, the first option in the screen is DESKTOP...number --- D:\
